# C# populating class array from xml linq results in FormatException

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm getting a FormatException error "Input string was not in a correct format." error...

Employee class is all strings except the Status(int), Type(int) and Displayed(bool)

```
public partial class Version2 : System.Web.UI.Page {

        private Employee[] Employees;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/")+ "V2Employees.xml");
                IEnumerable<XElement> emps = xdoc.Root.Descendants();

                Employees = emps.Select(x => new Employee()
                {
                    Employee_ID = x.Attribute("id").Value,
                    First_Name = x.Element("First_Name").Value,
                    Last_Name = x.Element("Last_Name").Value,
                    Classification_Group = x.Element("Classification_Group").Value,
                    Classification_Level = x.Element("Classification_Level").Value,
                    Postion_Number = x.Element("Postion_Number").Value,
                    English_Title = x.Element("English_Title").Value,
                    French_Title = x.Element("French_Title").Value,
                    Location = x.Element("Location").Value,
                    Language = x.Element("Language").Value,
                    Department_ID = x.Element("Department_ID").Value,
                    Status = int.Parse(x.Element("Status").ToString()),
                    Type = int.Parse(x.Element("Type").ToString()),
                    Displayed = false}).ToArray();
        }
```

Example XML going in:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <employees>
      <employee id="1">
        <First_Name>Jane</First_Name>
        <Last_Name>Doe</Last_Name>
        <Classification_Group>AA</Classification_Group>
        <Classification_Level>02</Classification_Level>
        <Postion_Number>12345</Postion_Number>
        <English_Title>Bob</English_Title>
        <French_Title></French_Title>
        <Location>Null Island</Location>
        <Language>English</Language>
        <Department_ID>000001</Department_ID>
        <Status>1</Status>
        <Type>4</Type>
      </employee>
</employees>
```

Comment: Could try commenting out all the lines then comment in one at a time to find the one that's causing the error

Comment: You have `x.Element("Status").ToString()` shouldnt this be `x.Element("Status").Value.ToString()`, similar with the line below.

Comment: Or just `x.Element("Status").Value` given that the type of `XElement.Value` is `string`, or just use a conversion: `(string) x.Element("Status")` to get the string value, or better yet, just use the conversion from `XElement` to `int`: `(int) `x.Element("Status")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See code below.  The fix was : xdoc.Root.Descendants("employee");  I also made other improvements

```
    public class Employee
    {
        static Employee[] Employees = null;

        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        public static Boolean IsPostBack = false;

        string Employee_ID { get; set; }
        string First_Name { get; set; }
        string Last_Name { get; set; }
        string Classification_Group { get; set; }
        string Classification_Level { get; set; }
        string Postion_Number { get; set; }
        string English_Title { get; set; }
        string French_Title { get; set; }
        string Location { get; set; }
        string Language { get; set; }
        string Department_ID { get; set; }
        int Status { get; set; }
        int Type { get; set; }
        Boolean Displayed { get; set; }


        //protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        public void Page_Load()
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
                IEnumerable<XElement> emps = xdoc.Root.Descendants("employee");

                Employees = emps.Select(x => new Employee()
                {
                    Employee_ID = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
                    First_Name = (string)x.Element("First_Name"),
                    Last_Name = (string)x.Element("Last_Name"),
                    Classification_Group = (string)x.Element("Classification_Group"),
                    Classification_Level = (string)x.Element("Classification_Level"),
                    Postion_Number = (string)x.Element("Postion_Number"),
                    English_Title = (string)x.Element("English_Title"),
                    French_Title = (string)x.Element("French_Title"),
                    Location = (string)x.Element("Location"),
                    Language = (string)x.Element("Language"),
                    Department_ID = (string)x.Element("Department_ID"),
                    Status = (int)x.Element("Status"),
                    Type = (int)x.Element("Type"),
                    Displayed = false
                }).ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

By calling `ToString` on an `XElement`, you're ending up with the whole element as a string, e.g.

```
<Status>4</Status>
```

... and trying to parse that as an `int`. I would strongly suggest:

- Just using the `Value` property or a cast to `string` when you want the value of an element as a string (no need for a `ToString` call afterwards)
- Using a cast to `int` when you want to convert an `XElement`'s value to an integer

I would write your `Select` as:

```
// Property names adjusted to .NET naming conventions, type of
// PositionNumber changed to an int.
Employees = emps.Select(x => new Employee
{
    EmployeeId = (string) x.Attribute("id"),
    FirstName = (string) x.Element("First_Name"),
    LastName = (string) x.Element("Last_Name"),
    ClassificationGroup = (string) x.Element("Classification_Group"),
    ClassificationLevel = (string) x.Element("Classification_Level"),
    PositionNumber = (int) x.Element("Postion_Number"),
    EnglishTitle = (string) x.Element("English_Title"),
    FrenchTitle = (string) x.Element("French_Title"),
    Location = (string) x.Element("Location"),
    Language = (string) x.Element("Language"),
    DepartmentId = (string) x.Element("Department_ID"),
    Status = (int) x.Element("Status"),
    Type = (int) x.Element("Type"),
    Displayed = false
}
```

You *might* want to use `.Value` instead of the cast to `string`, which will mean you get a `NullReferenceException` if the element is missing the appropriate sub-element. You may want to use the above form instead, then have a `Validate` method to check that it has all the required information - that would probably allow you to report errors more clearly:

- You could say which property is missing rather than just getting an exception
- You could report multiple missing properties in a single error message